# mysql wont start after update (seems an apparmor issue)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, apparmor

I just updated mysql-server to 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 and MySQL does not restart anymore. `dmesg` shows following errors:

```
[  832.490460] type=1400 audit(1392612759.575:31): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=16498 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  832.543672] type=1400 audit(1392612759.627:32): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=16532 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  833.740580] init: mysql main process (16544) terminated with status 1
[  833.740615] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[  834.687079] init: mysql post-start process (16545) terminated with status 1
[  834.695901] type=1400 audit(1392612761.779:33): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=16622 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  835.889156] init: mysql main process (16643) terminated with status 1
[  835.889203] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[  836.763574] init: mysql post-start process (16644) terminated with status 1
[  836.773149] type=1400 audit(1392612763.859:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=16724 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  837.928074] init: mysql main process (16736) terminated with status 1
[  837.928110] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

Seems like AppArmor doesn't let `mysqld` to restart. I dont know much about how apparmor works and have no idea how to debu this. Could anyone help please?

Comment: check if your mysql data directory volume is mounted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AskUbuntu Q&A sounds like your issue, titled: [Can't start mysql - mysql respawning too fast, stopped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped).

*excerpt from that answer*

> Run the following:
>
> ```
>    # Miraz added dpkg-reconfigure
>    dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
> ```
>
> But make sure there's no old mysql version installation installed, if there was please remove:
>
> ```
>    # Miraz quick mysql package check
>    dpkg -l *mysql*
> ```